# Do superluminal worldlines constitute closed time-like curves under the right conditions?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, faster-than-light, tachyon, closed-timelike-curve

A closed time-like curve is defined as a word-line that returns to its starting point, in the $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ coordinates. So, for a chronology respecting observer, an object traversing a closed time-like curve would appear to violate causality. Under certain conditions (Tolman et al.), superluminal propagation of signals also appears to violate causality. 
Does this indicate that for a tachyonic anti-telephone situation, the worldline of a superluminal tachyon could be considered as a closed time-like curve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The world-line of a tachyon is spacelike. That's the definition of a tachyon. That means it can't be a closed timelike curve.

The existence of CTCs is a property of the spacetime, not of the particles inhabiting it. Minkowski space simply doesn't have CTCs.

Comment: I see. And does the same logic apply to other methods of apparent superluminal motions, like wormholes?

Comment: @CuriousDroid: No, in a traversable wormhole, there really can be CTCs. That is a different property of that spacetime.

Comment: I see. So a wormhole that allows for superluminal motion relative to an outside observer, but that does not have a relative time shift between the mouths, that would NOT produce a CTC, but still allow for an apparent causality violation?